# Multi clients not working properly on Qt4 Multi thread server?

Tags: c++, multithreading, file-io, client-server, qt4

Friends! I have written a code for a *multi threaded TCP server* in Qt4. The server is constantly listening for remote client connection requests. Whenever the client connects to the server, it takes its IP, Name and Port number and verifies if it is a recognized (authorized) client (that can be checked through a *pre-stored text file* having names, IPs and port numbers of all registered clients). If it is, the communication will proceed. Otherwise, the server terminates the connection.

**EDIT1:** here is the excerpt from **myThread.cpp**

```
void MyThread::run()
{
    // Thread starts here
    qDebug() << socketDescriptor << ("Starting thread...");
    socket = new QTcpSocket();

    if(!socket->setSocketDescriptor(this->socketDescriptor))
    {
        emit error(socket->error());
        return;
    }

    connect(socket, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(readyRead()), Qt::DirectConnection);
    connect(socket, SIGNAL(disconnected()), this, SLOT(disconnected()), Qt::DirectConnection);

    qDebug() << socketDescriptor << ("Client connected!");

    exec();
}
```

**ISSUE**: Now the problem is when I run the program and connects the first client it works fine. But as soon as the 2nd client is connected (testing through telnet, for now) it starts behaving strange (no messages receiving from client 2 or client 2 completely freezing etc). Can someone test the code in their machine?

**myserver.cpp**

```
#include "myserver.h"
#include "ioprogram.h"
#include <QTcpSocket>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

MyServer::MyServer(QObject *parent): QTcpServer(parent)
{
    QStringList accepted_ip_list;   //List of remote IPs that can be accepted in QString list format
    accepted_ip_list.append("127.0.0.1");   // IPv4 local address
    accepted_ip_list.append("::1");         // IPv6 local address

    accepted_ip_list.append("172.18.48.139");

    // Convert from QString to integer format, generating new list
    foreach (const QString &ip, accepted_ip_list)
    {
        QHostAddress host_address(ip);
        my_accepted_ip_list.append(host_address);
    }
/*
    myserver = new QTcpServer(this);

    connect(myserver, &QTcpServer::incomingConnection, this, &MyServer::incomingConnection);

    myserver->listen(QHostAddress::Any, 1234);
*/
}

void MyServer::startServer()
{
    if(!this->listen(QHostAddress::Any,1234))
    {
        qDebug() << "Could not start server.";
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug() << "Listening...";
    }
}

void MyServer::incomingConnection(qintptr socketDescriptor)
{
    QTcpSocket *socket = new QTcpSocket(this);
    socket->setSocketDescriptor(socketDescriptor);

    qDebug() << socketDescriptor << "Connecting...";

    QHostAddress host_address = socket->peerAddress();

    //quint32 ipv4 = host_address.toIPv4Address();
    std::string ipv4 = host_address.toString().toStdString();

    QByteArray ipv6 = QByteArray((char*)host_address.toIPv6Address().c, 16);

    IOProgram test;

    bool status= test.checkAuthenticity(ipv4);

    if(status == false){
        /*
    while (myserver->hasPendingConnections())
    {
        QTcpSocket *socket = myserver->nextPendingConnection();
        QHostAddress host_address = socket->peerAddress();

        bool contains = false;
*/
        for(int i=0; i < my_accepted_ip_list.size(); i++)
        {
            //quint32 accepted_ipv4 = my_accepted_ip_list[i].toIPv4Address();
            std::string accepted_ipv4 = my_accepted_ip_list[i].toString().toStdString();

            if(accepted_ipv4 == ipv4)
            {
                status = true;
                qDebug() << "testing...";
                break;
            }
       /*     else
            {
                qDebug() << "Rejected!";
                socket->abort();        // Reject peer by disconnecting it
                socket->deleteLater();  // Schedule the socket removal from memory
            }
        */
            /*if(my_accepted_ip_list[i].isEqual(host_address,QHostAddress::ConvertV4MappedToIPv4))
            {
                contains = true;
                break;
            }*/
        }

        if(!socket->QTcpSocket::ConnectedState){
            socket->abort();        // Reject peer by disconnecting it
            socket->deleteLater();  // Schedule the socket removal from memory
        }

        if(status)
        {
            qDebug() << "Accepted!";
            MyThread *thread = new MyThread(socketDescriptor, this);

            connect(thread, SIGNAL(finished()), thread, SLOT(deleteLater()));
            thread->start();
        }
    }
}
```

**ioprogram.cpp**

```
#include "ioprogram.h"
#include <QFile>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QTextStream>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

    struct Data {
        string Name;
        string IP;
        string Port;
    };

    vector<Data> AllData;

IOProgram::IOProgram()
{

}

void Read()
{
    QFile file("C:/Users/Shahwani/Documents/Bremen/Sem3/Qt/MultiServerAugust/NodesList.txt");

    if(file.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite | QIODevice::Text))
    {
        QTextStream stream(&file);

        QString line;
        do
        {
            line = stream.readLine();
            qDebug() << line;
        }while(!line.isNull());

        file.close();
    }
}

string IOProgram::inpop()
{
    ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open("NodesList.txt");
//    inFile.clear();

    // Check for error
    if(inFile.fail()){
        cerr << "Error opening file" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    int count = 0;
    string line;
    char delim = '\t';
    getline (inFile,line);

    // Read the file until the end
    while(!inFile.eof())
    {
        getline (inFile,line);

        string token;
        stringstream stream(line);          // Splitting a string using a delimiter
        vector<string> vect;
        while(getline(stream, token, delim) )
        {
            vect.push_back(token);
        }
        Data d;
        d.Name = vect[0];
        d.IP = vect[1];
        d.Port = vect[2];
        vect.clear();
        AllData.push_back(d);
        count++;
    }

    cout << count << " nodes found!" << endl;
    inFile.close();

    // Check for authenticity and only allow the recognised IPs


    // Write the active nodes in a separate file on the disk

    ofstream outFile;
    outFile.open("sample.txt");
    Data activeList;
    for(int i = 0; i < AllData.size(); i++)
    {
        activeList = AllData[i];
        outFile << "Name: " << activeList.Name << "\tIP: " << activeList.IP << "\tPort: " << activeList.Port <<endl;
    }

    outFile.close();

    return activeList.IP;
}

bool IOProgram::checkAuthenticity(string ip)
{
    for(int i=0;i<AllData.size();i++)
    {
        Data check;
        check = AllData[i];
        if(ip == check.IP)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

I guess I cannot put a lot of code in one question. Let me know in case someone needs rest of the files like **mythread.cpp** or **header files** to understand the issue and how I can share them.

Comment: You appear to be moving the socket descriptor to the new `MyThread` but not the associated `QTcpSocket`.  Have a look at the [docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcpserver.html#incomingConnection).

Comment: @G.M. I didn't get your point properly. You mean I have to change _socketDescriptor_ here: `MyThread *thread = new MyThread(socketDescriptor, this);`

Comment: The second **Note** in the link I gave states "Note: If you want to handle an incoming connection as a new QTcpSocket object in another thread you have to pass the socketDescriptor to the other thread and create the QTcpSocket object there and use its setSocketDescriptor() method".  You don't appear to be doing that.

Comment: I'm actually doing that in the `run()` function of **myThread.cpp** kindly see the edited question above!

Comment: But you've already created a `QTcpSocket` wrapper for the descriptor at the top of `MyServer::incomingConnection`.  So you appear to have two `QTcpSocket` objects on different threads managing the same descriptor.

Comment: @G.M. yeah! now I'm getting your point. Should I comment out the one in `MyServer::incomingConnection` ?